# Query Values in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I am trying to generate a TLS certificate for all of the ingress resources in my Helm chart. My helm chart contains an application with multiple backends so my Values.yaml is structed like this:

```
backend1:
  ingress:
    host: testing.app.com
    tls:
      - secretName: my-tls-cert
        hosts:
          - testing.app.com
backend2:
  ingress:
    host: testing.app.com
    tls:
      - secretName: idp-cts-cert
        hosts:
          - idp-cts
db
  creds: ""

serviceName: ""
```

Notice there is a mixture of maps and string values. My goal is to use a utility template I wrote to call `genSignedCert` and generate one TLS cert that has the hosts listed  as a CN or alternate name:

```
{{/*
Return a self-signed TLS certificate
{{ include "common.certs.ingress-tls" .hosts  }}
*/}}
{{- define "common.certs.gen-cert" -}}
{{- $hostlist := toStrings . -}}
{{- $cn := (first $hostlist) -}}
{{- $altnames := uniq (rest $hostlist) -}}
{{- $ca := genCA "idp-ca" 365 -}}
{{- $cert := genSignedCert $cn nil $altnames 365 $ca -}}
tls.crt: {{ $cert.Cert | b64enc }}
tls.key: {{ $cert.Key | b64enc }}
{{- end -}}
```

I have tried iterating over the Values and but I cannot come up with workable code to do this.

Edit1: I am aware of the security implications of using self-signed certificates. The bad values.yaml structure is inherited from the fact that this is an umbrella chart and each backed is also it's own chart. A refactor of the charts structure may be required, but I wanted to exhaust all options first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider generating the TLS certificate outside Helm, and injecting it via values (or storing its components in a Secret directly).  This avoids some complicated code here.  There is a more serious problem, though: every time you call `genCA` and `genSignedCert` it creates a new certificate, so every time you upgrade you'll get a different certificate, and for that matter if you call this template once per Ingress object, each will have a different certificate.

---

It'd help this problem to restructure the `values.yaml` slightly.  It's hard for code to tell that `backend1` is a backend specification, but `serviceName` isn't.  If you just have a list of `backends` this gets easier:

```yaml
backends:
  - ingress:
      host: testing.app.com
      ...
  - ingress:
      host: testing.app.com
      ...
```

You'll then hit a couple of limitations of Helm templates as a full-featured programming language.  Templates only ever return strings, so you can't write a template that returns a list.  You can't pass a function as a parameter to a template, so you can't write a general-purpose `map` (in limited cases you can pass a template name and `include` it).

What you can do is write a recursive function that passes the partial list forward to the next iteration, and then invokes the final generator when it's done.  In Python, we might write:

```py
def generateCertificate(backends, tls, hosts):
  # If `tls` is non-empty, take the first item from it and add its
  # hosts to the `hosts` list; then recurse with the same backend
  # list, the remaining `tls` items, and the updated `hosts`:
  if len(tls) > 0:
    return generateCertificate(backends, tls[1:], hosts + tls[0].hosts)
  # If `tls` is empty but `backends` is non-empty, take the first
  # backend, and recurse with the remaining `backends`, the `tls` items
  # from the selected backend, and the same `hosts`:
  else if len(backends) > 0:
    return generateCertificate(backends[1:], backends[0].tls, hosts)
  # If `tls` and `backends` are both empty, we're done
  else:
    return buildTheCertificate(hosts)

certificate = generateCertificate(values.backends, [], [])
```

We can convert this logic into Go templates:

```
{{/* Emit a TLS certificate given the list of backends.  The
parameter is a dictionary with keys `backends`, `tls`, and `hosts`. */}}
{{- define "common.certs.gen-cert" -}}
{{- if .tls -}}
  {{- include "common.certs.gen-cert" (dict "backends" .backend "tls" (last .tls) "hosts" (concat .hosts (head .tls).hosts)) -}}
{{- else if .backends -}}
  {{- include "common.certs.gen-cert" (dict "backends" (tail .backends) "tls" (head .backends).tls "hosts" .hosts) -}}
{{- else -}}
  {{- include "common.certs.gen-cert-hosts" .hosts -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

{{/* Actually generate a TLS certificate from a list of host names.
Note, the certificate will be regenerated on every call.  The
single parameter is a list of names. */}}
{{- define "common.certs.gen-cert-hosts" -}}
{{- $cn := first . -}}
{{- $altnames := rest . | uniq -}}
{{- $ca := genCA "idp-ca" 365 -}}
{{- $cert := genSignedCert $cn nil $altnames 365 $ca -}}
tls.crt: {{ $cert.Cert | b64enc }}
tls.key: {{ $cert.Key | b64enc }}
{{- end -}}

{{- include "common.certs.gen-cert" (dict "backends" .Values.backends) -}}
```

This is enough intricate code that it's probably worth unit-testing it.  Setting this up is left as an exercise; Helm does not have any sort of native support here.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and detailed answer. I also made some edits to my question. You mention writing  a Python script to generate the certificate beforehand, but I was trying to keep the installation steps to as few of steps as possible. Would you recommend keeping it in the helm charts or wrapping the installation in a script?

Comment: For production use, you'll have to get an externally-signed certificate and inject that somehow, and I might use the same workflow in pre-production.  How exactly you inject the certificate is a large question in itself (passing it as a Helm value and creating a Secret might not be secure enough).

Comment: The Python fragment was intended to be the same as the Helm template fragment, but in a language that's a little bit more mainstream.  (Since Python _does_ have `map` and `lambda` and list comprehensions, I probably wouldn't write this function that way.)